# How do I call all comments for a post (workout in this case) where workout.user_id == current_user.id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have created a Ruby on Rails app where users can record their workouts and other users can comment on those workouts. I am using a Dashboard resource to aggregate information for current_user. I am trying to display recent comments on a current_user's workouts but can't seem to figure out how to do this correctly. I think I need a named_scope which I am not great at yet.

I essentially want the app to loop through the comments table but only return comments on Workouts where workout.user_id == to current_user.id.

/views/dashboard/index.html.erb

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %> 
  <%= link_to (comment.user.username), comment.user %><br/>
  <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %><br/>
  <%= link_to (comment.workout.title), comment.workout %><br/>
<% end %>
```

dashboard_controller.rb

```
def index
  @comments = Comment.all(:order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 10)
  @workouts = Workout.all(:order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 10) 
end
```

*I don't think I need the @workouts line in their but put it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the models setup properly, here's something you can try:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :for_user, lambda { |user| { :joins => :workout, :conditions => ["workouts.user_id = ?", user.id] } }
  named_scope :order, lambda { |order| { :order => order } }
  named_scope :limit, lambda { |limit| { :limit => limit } }
end

class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comments = Comment.for_user(current_user).order("created_at DESC").limit(10)
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for using named_scope with lambdas. Only, no need to create one for order and limit, use the built-in ActiveRecord way, like the original post says.

Comment: those are only available in Rails 3 or if you use a ActiveRecord backport for Rails 2.x

Comment: Yea, I'm using 2.3.8 for this project

Comment: I get this error when using the above `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: workout.user_id: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"   INNER JOIN "workouts" ON "workouts".id = "comments".workout_id  WHERE (workout.user_id = 1) `

Comment: Sorry, it should be "workouts.user_id = ?" in the conditions. I have updated this

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do is to put relations between your models, i.e. comment and workout. Each workout can have many comments, and each comment belongs to a workout. So:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :workout

      # rest of the model definitions
end
```

and

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :comments

      # rest of the model definitions
end
```

Once you set it up like this, then you can call:

```
<% @workout.comments do |comment| %> 
   <!-- print comment here -->
<% end %>
```

You can follow the example [here](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec%3ademo_user_has_many_microposts).

Comment: I have this relationship set up. When I use the @workout.comments do |comment| I get `undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Then, I guess something is wrong with your setup. Dig further. It might be easier to work in console.

Comment: You can get instant online help in the #rubyonrails IRC channel on freenode: http://webchat.freenode.net/

Comment: I suspect that your @workout is actually undefined. Were you trying to loop through everything in @workouts? If so, the local variable is likely to be workout and not @workout