# Looking for a short term fix for limiting record display number without :limit => 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am wondering if there is a way to complete this hack that I am trying to do with my Ruby on Rails app. I'm having trouble with some associations and I can't find the solution. You can [see that question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311074/how-do-i-call-all-comments-for-a-post-workout-in-this-case-where-workout-user-i).

In the mean time I am wanting to limit the display of records to a number like `10` but I don't want to do it in the controller through the `:limit => 10` manner because I need to loop through all the records. I'm not even sure if this is possible but thought I would ask.

My view code is:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% if comment.workout.user_id == current_user.id %><br/>
    <%= link_to (comment.user.username), comment.user %> <br/>
    <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> <br/>
    <%= link_to (comment.workout.title), comment.workout %><br/>
    <%= sanitize(simple_format(comment.body), :tags => %w(p)) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My controller is simply calling

```
@comments = Comment.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
```

Comment: When you mean you need to loop through all records, you mean in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do all that in the controller. Views shouldn't be doing that logic. You say you don't want to only limit to 10, because you want all and do some filter. You can just:

```
@comments = Comment.all(:joins => :workout, :conditions => {:workouts =>{:user_id => current_user.id}}, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 10)
```

Comment: this looks like it might answer both my questions. I am getting this error though `Association named 'workouts' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: fixed it. Just changed the :workouts to :workout in the first mention.

Comment: I would go ahead and post this answer on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@comments[0..9]
```

and

```
@comments[10..-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the [will-paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem the droid you're looking for?

After adding the gem to your environment.rb and installing it, you would modify your controller so that it calls paginate rather than `find` or `all`:

```
@comments = Comment.paginate(:all, :order => "created_at DESC", :per_page => 10)
```

And then in your view, add the pagination controls (links to advance a page, go back a page, &c.)

```
<%= will_paginate @comments %>
```